# scrartcl produces \par in last line of document

Tags: paragraphs, parskip, scrartcl

You can see here

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    |\hfill|\\
    %\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
    Datum, Ort \hfill Unterschrift Mieter%
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]
that there is a `\par` at the end of the document. Why?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you presumably want the final paragraph to be line wrapped and added to the document so a `\par` is needed. You say this is annoying, but I can not guess what behaviour you would expect? Without a `\par` the final paragraph would not be added to the document at all.

Comment: I want the space at the end of the last line to disappear. This can be done by using `\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}` but I find it strange that it is not the default behavior. Why would you want to add space at the last line of a document?

Comment: the default parfilskip has natural size 0pt but you have explicitly chosen a document class option to force that no paragraph has a full last line, why should the last paragraph of the document have a different rule?  But also your question does not ask about that space, it asks why there is a `\par` and that is a very different question as it is the `\par` behaviour that makes the text appear at all.

Comment: Yes, this is also the question to get a better understanding of what is happening at parsing time. Also I don't find this behavior annoying any more because I know what is happening. I deleted my previous opinion about being annoyed.

Comment: you could use `parskip=half-` which allows the last line to be full.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Good [info](https://golatex.de/unterschied-zwischen-parskiphalf-und-parskiphalf-t19776.html).

Comment: that does of course affect the whole document, not just the last paragraph, although you can change the setting mid-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text that is added to a paragraph is accumulated in one long horizontal list and only when `\par` (or display math) is encountered, the horizontal list is broken into lines and each line box and associated `\baselineskip` glue is added to the vertical list that makes up the page.

So if the end document didn't force the `\par` behaviour the final paragraph of the document would be lost. (This isn't actually possible as if `\enddocument` didn't force par TeX's primitive `\end` to stop the document adds `\par` if encountered in horizontal mode.)

If you want to add a non-paragraph line of text you could use

```
\hbox to \textwidth{Datum, Ort \hfill Unterschrift Mieter}
```

Or as you show in the code comment you could reset `\parfillskip` for the final paragraph, best to set it to 0pt with no `fill` component, so that the `\hfill` takes up all the space.

```
Datum, Ort \hfill Unterschrift Mieter\parfillskip=0pt
```

Alternatively, as I noted in the comments under the question, you could use `parskip=half-` option which would remove this minimum space requirement from the last line of paragraphs (for the whole document). As this option leaves `\oarfillskip` with its default value, with natural size 0pt.